# How to copy data of one file to another using only AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, file, copy

I've been trying to copy data of "file1.txt" to "file2.txt" at the click of a button with the help of AJAX.

Below is my code, but it doesn't seem to work correctly. Data to be copied is just some Lorem Ipsum text.

Also, what is `data` in the `success` of the second `$.ajax()` call? I'm a bit confused.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var x;

  $(".btn").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "file1.txt",
      success: function(data) {
        x = data;
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: "file2.txt",
          data: x,
          success: function(data) {
            alert("Success!");
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: what is your backend technology? ajax simply means doing process in background without letting user know about it!

Comment: So, I can't write a file using 'only' ajax? What other technology do I need?

Comment: no with plain simple ajax it is not possible, you will need something in the backend(server side) I suggest php, with php you can easily copy data from one file to another!

Comment: can I use node.js?

Comment: Yes you can use nodejs